# Regex Newline Jboss

Tags: regex, jboss, notepad++

I have a regular expression which works in notepad++ when ". matches newline" is selected, but not in JBoss file search.

What is the regular expression for that ". matches newline" option, since I want to be able to use the same regular expression in JBoss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem:

In notepad++ there is a feature in Search tab --> Find in Files...
Post the path where all the files are located. Check Regular Expression and matches newline. Enter your regex and click find all.

Answer (score 0):

The modifier to use for "dot matches newline" is `(?s)` (Single line mode), ie.: `(?s)\w\.\w`

Comment: I tried <tr[^>]*>(((?s)\w\.\w).)*((?!<tr[^>]*>|</tr>|<td>|</td>).)*</tr> and <tr[^>]*>((?s)\w\.\w)((?!<tr[^>]*>|</tr>|<td>|</td>).)*</tr>. Both regex expressions didn't work when I turned newline off.